# Artifactory jfrog - download artifact with regex and exclude

Tags: regex, jenkins, ant, artifactory

I'm just trying to download every artifact for example:

```
maven-dsd-snapshot-local/com/dsds/aem/tenants/dcihub/dcihub-wrapper/1221.1.0-SNAPSHOT
/something-wrapper-2023.1.0-20230206.113149-31.zip
```

but NOT

```
maven-dsd-snapshot-local/com/dsds/aem/platform/platform-wrapper/2023.1.0-SNAPSHOT/platform-wrapper-2023.1.0-20230206.113149-51.zip
```

That is what I'm trying to do in Jenkins using Artifactory plugin:

```
    Artifactory_BUILD_PATH = """{
                   "files": [
                  {
                    "pattern": "${repo}/(?!.*platform-wrapper).*-wrapper/.*.zip",
                    "target": "/tmp/artifacts/",
                    "flat": "true",
                    "build": "${buildName}/LATEST"
                  }
                 ]
                }"""
```

However when I do that I get:

```
  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

With negative regex this works and match correctly all the wrapper paths:

```
    Artifactory_BUILD_PATH = """{
                   "files": [
                  {
                    "pattern": "${repo}/*-wrapper/*.zip",
                    "target": "/tmp/artifacts/",
                    "flat": "true",
                    "build": "${buildName}/LATEST"
                  }
                 ]
                }"""
```

END GOAL:
Match all paths that have wrapper in it, but exclude platform-wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

The download command only supports wildcards. It does not support regular expressions.

You can make use of the `exclusions` field in order to exclude certain paths.

See the [File Specs documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Using+File+Specs) for more details.

Comment: I tried with exclusions, but still doesn't work

Comment: "pattern": "${repo}/*-wrapper/*.zip",
                            "exclusions": ["*platform*.zip"], just gets ignored

Comment: plugin version?